# Users not able to login in AEM

Tags: aem

The Ldap group users are not able to login in AEM. I am getting the below error.

All the users taht we have set up manually are able to login. Also, the admin user is working.

All the other functionalities are also working.......................................................................

```
 *ERROR* [qtp1013336206-6325] org.apache.sling.engine.impl.parameters.ParameterSupport getRequestParameterMapInternal: Error parsing request
org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException: Early EOF
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpInput$3.noContent(HttpInput.java:505)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpInput.read(HttpInput.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpInput.read(HttpInput.java:109)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.parameters.Util.parseNVPairString(Util.java:242)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.parameters.Util.parseQueryString(Util.java:215)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.parameters.ParameterSupport.getRequestParameterMapInternal(ParameterSupport.java:265)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.parameters.ParameterSupport.getParameter(ParameterSupport.java:173)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.parameters.ParameterSupportHttpServletRequestWrapper2x.getParameter(ParameterSupportHttpServletRequestWrapper2x.java:38)
    at com.day.crx.security.token.impl.TokenAuthenticationHandler.getTokenFormPars(TokenAuthenticationHandler.java:669)
    at com.day.crx.security.token.impl.TokenAuthenticationHandler.extractCredentials(TokenAuthenticationHandler.java:445)
    at org.apache.sling.auth.core.impl.AuthenticationHandlerHolder.doExtractCredentials(AuthenticationHandlerHolder.java:75)
    at org.apache.sling.auth.core.impl.AbstractAuthenticationHandlerHolder.extractCredentials(AbstractAuthenticationHandlerHolder.java:60)
    at org.apache.sling.auth.core.impl.SlingAuthenticator.getAuthenticationInfo(SlingAuthenticator.java:709)
    at org.apache.sling.auth.core.impl.SlingAuthenticator.doHandleSecurity(SlingAuthenticator.java:461)
    at org.apache.sling.auth.core.impl.SlingAuthenticator.handleSecurity(SlingAuthenticator.java:446)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingHttpContext.handleSecurity(SlingHttpContext.java:121)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.context.ServletContextImpl.handleSecurity(ServletContextImpl.java:339)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:334)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:297)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.ServletPipeline.handle(ServletPipeline.java:93)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:50)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
    at org.apache.sling.security.impl.ReferrerFilter.doFilter(ReferrerFilter.java:290)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
    at org.apache.felix.http.sslfilter.internal.SslFilter.doFilter(SslFilter.java:89)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
    at com.adobe.granite.license.impl.LicenseCheckFilter.doFilter(LicenseCheckFilter.java:308)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
    at org.apache.sling.i18n.impl.I18NFilter.doFilter(I18NFilter.java:129)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
    at org.apache.sling.featureflags.impl.FeatureManager.doFilter(FeatureManager.java:115)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.log.RequestLoggerFilter.doFilter(RequestLoggerFilter.java:75)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.FilterPipeline.dispatch(FilterPipeline.java:76)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.Dispatcher.dispatch(Dispatcher.java:49)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.DispatcherServlet.service(DispatcherServlet.java:67)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:808)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:587)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
02.10.2017 11:06:49.767 *WARN* [qtp1013336206-6325] org.apache.sling.auth.core.impl.SlingAuthenticator handleSecurity: AuthenticationHandler did not block request; access denied
```

Can anyone help, please?
Thanks!

Comment: Was it working before? Check this [link](http://www.adobeaemclub.com/custom-external-login-module/)